# Why am I getting a "wrong number of arguments errors (0 for 1)"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

**The Error**

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

**My controller:**

```
def new_topic
  @new_topic = MeTopic.new(:me_category_id => params[:category])

  render :nothing => true
end
```

**My view:**

```
  .new_topic_form
    - form_tag new_topic_admin_me_categories_path(:category => category.id) do
      = text_field_tag, "name"
      %br/
      = submit_tag 'Publish', :class => 'button'
```

**my routes**

```
admin.resources :me_categories, :collection => {:destroy_topic => :get, :new_topic => :get}
```

If I remove the text_field_tag, then everything loads. Why would that text_field_tag bomb my app?

Comment: You have a comma in after text_field_tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the comma from the `= text_field_tag, "name"` so that you just have:

`= text_field_tag "name"`